# usertype value showing null in android

Tags: java, android

Hi In This code I am getting response by using json for that created one map in that I mention key and value.Now That value storing in one variable for that I wrote like this

```
String usertype = usertypeMap.get(user_type[i]);
```

But The usertype showing null can any one please help me where I did mistake.

**java**

```
 String username1 = usname.getText().toString();
               String password = pword.getText().toString();

               queryString = "username=" + username1 + "&password="
                        + password ;
               String user_type1 = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("usertype",queryString);
               System.out.print(user_type1);

               try
               {
                JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(user_type1);



                username = new String[JA.length()];
                user_type = new String[JA.length()];




                for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                {
                    username[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("username");
                    user_type[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_type");
                    usertypeMap.put(username[i],user_type[i]);
                }




               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
String usertype = usertypeMap.get(user_type[i]);
                   try{
                   queryString = "username=" + username1 + "&password="
                    + password +"&user_type="+usertype;
                   final String data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("login",queryString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting value from the value

Map is(KEY,VALUE). In your code, key is **username[i]** value is  **user_type[i]**. But you getting the value like this

```
String usertype = usertypeMap.get(user_type[i]);
```

try using like this

```
String usertype = usertypeMap.get(username[i]);
```